# Crystal Reports and Adding values

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I am using Crystal Reports XI and I'm trying to add a particular column if one column or another column is set to one.

Here is the current preview:

```
Username (GROUP 1)
    MONTH (GROUP 2)

        DATE      SUBJECT     TOTAL_TIME

    End of group 2
End of group 1
```

Now I want to add the values in total_time if one of the two hidden fields contain 1 (true).

I tried using sum() function but it didn't work as it added all the times together.

I'm still new to Crystal Reports and I tried searching on google but nothing came up similar to what I need.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative that I can suggest, You can use Parameter fields on your report.

Do the calculation on Code behind and set the calculated sum to parameter field on Page_Load event of Crystal Report page.
This parameter field will be used to display the sum on report page.

Please check this link to see 
-How to create Parameter Fields: 
http://devlibrary.businessobjects.com/BusinessObjectsXIR2/en/en/CrystalReports_dotNET_SDK/crsdk_net_doc/doc/crsdk_net_doc/html/crtsktutorialscrvparametersdiscretecreatingreport.htm

-How to set values in Parameter Fields: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289936(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Your best option will be use "Running totals" by this way you can control the flow by keeping a condition to sum when the required column is 1.

Comment: This won't work as it's summing everything as soon as one of the columns hits 1 it sums even those with the column 0 or null

Answer (score 0):

Did you think about small trick? You wrote: *I want to add the values in totaltime if one of the two hidden fields contain 1 (true).*

Under these circumstances you can calculate helper field `Total_Time_Conditional` using formula:

`Total_Time_Conditional = IIf(HiddenField1 = 1 or HiddenField2 = 1, 1, 0) * Total_Time`.

This will multiply  `Total_Time`

- by 1, if any of hidden fields is 1
- by 0, if both hidden fields are 0

Calculating `Sum(Total_Time_Conditional)` will give you expected result.